# Moving A UIButton from Sprite-Kit scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, viewcontroller

Working with Game Center I decided to create a UIButton which I've called Leaderboards. The problem is that on myScene when the Start Button (a sprite-kit node), gets touched I need to move leaderboards off the screen but cannot do this since it occurs on myScene and not the ViewController.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Start"]) {
        self.Start.position = CGPointMake(-100, -100);
        self.Instructions.position = CGPointMake(-100, -100);
        //Leaderboards need to be moved off screen now.
    }
}
```

In the ViewController I would use the code below to move the Leaderboards button off the screen, but cannot use this on myScene.

```
    Leaderboards.center = CGPointMake(-100, -100);
```

Currently the UIButton remains visible on the screen distrupting the game. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your Scene a reference to its parent view controller in MyScene.h:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyScene : SKScene

@property (nonatomic,weak) MyViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Then in MyViewController.m when you create the scene:

```
// Create and configure the scene.
MyScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

//assign self to the view controller property
scene.viewController = self;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

and create method:

```
-(void)moveLeaderButton{
    _leaderButton.center = CGPointMake(-100, -100);
}
```

also put it in MyViewController.h:

```
-(void)moveLeaderButton;
```

Then in MyScene.m you can call method:

```
[_viewController moveLeaderButton];
```